# Did Stack Overflow get designed by Jeff and Joel?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, jeff-atwood, joel-spolsky

Was Stack Overflow designed by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky in the first place? (In 2008)

I am talking about graphical and functional design.

Comment: Are you talking about graphical, functional or technical design?

Comment: @Chichiray Sorry, I have forgot to add this. [Updated the question]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Graphical - No, not really. Proof:

> We’re currently at the stage where we need to implement an actual design — **for which I have recruited actual designers** [...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-beta-design/)

- Functional - Yes

Comment: Ugh, look at all the horrid "Preamble:" and "Hi:" prefixes in those "questions". What a waste.